# Summing the Euler $\varphi$-function $\varphi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, totient-function

The Euler $\varphi$-function $\varphi(n)$ counts the number of positive integers less than or equal to $n$,
which are relatively prime with $n$.
I would like to evaluate

$$ \sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d) $$and prove that the  answer is correct.

Comment: Do you know group theory?

Comment: I do not. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Levent can you give the proof using group theory?

Comment: What do you want to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the sets $A_q = \{(n,k)=q \mid 1 \leq k \leq n\}$. As you can see, total number of elements of $A_1, \dots, A_n$ is equal to $n$ since for each $i \neq j $, $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset $.

Now let us check how many elements does $A_d$ have:
If $x \in A_d$ then $(n,x)=d$ so that $(\frac{n}{d},\frac{x}{d})=1$. Then we can say that the number of such $x$'s is equal to $\varphi(\frac{n}{d})$.
$\implies |A_d|=\varphi(\frac{n}{d})$.

Going back to our sum:

$\sum_{d \mid n} \varphi(d) = \sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(\frac{n}{d})= \sum_{d \mid n}|A_d| =n$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

$\varphi(n)$ is a multiplicative function, i.e. 
$$\varphi(a b) = \varphi(a)\cdot\varphi(b) \tag{0}$$
for any $a,b\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. By assuming that 
$$ n = p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{\alpha_k} $$
is the factorization of $n$, from $(0)$ we have:
$$ \sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d) = \prod_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{h=0}^{\alpha_j}\varphi(p_j^h) \tag{1}$$
but:
$$ \varphi(p^h) = p^{h}-p^{h-1}, \tag{2}$$
hence the RHS of $(1)$ contains a telescopic sum and:
$$ \sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d) = \prod_{j=1}^{k} p_j^{\alpha_j}=\color{red}{n}.\tag{3}$$

Another (group-theoretic) proof is just [on the Wikipedia page about the totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Divisor_sum).

Comment: I do not know most of the notation you have used in your solution. Is there a more basic way to solve this (even if it is a longer, wordier proof/solution)?

Comment: What are the obscure notations? $\prod$ and $\sum$?

Comment: The obscure notations are $∏ $and $p^α1⋅…⋅p^αk$

Comment: @Interest: that simply means that we write $n$ as the product ($\prod$) of distint prime powers (the prime $p_i$ has the exponent $\alpha_i$), i.e. we apply the unique factorization theorem.   i707107: no problem, well done.

Comment: @Interest: again, $$\prod_{k=1}^{n} f(k) = f(1)\cdot f(2)\cdot\ldots\cdot f(n).$$

Comment: In (1), are you using the fact that $F(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)$ is also multiplicative?

Comment: @user84413: no, it is a consequence of $(1)$. Any divisor $d$ can be written as $p_1^{\beta_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{\beta_k}$, whose $\varphi$ is $\varphi(p_1^{\beta_1})\cdot\ldots\cdot\varphi(p_k^{\beta_k})$. By rearranging, we get $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks -- I see what you mean.