# Some properties of greatest integer factor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $L:{\Bbb N}\backslash \{ 1\}  \to {\Bbb N}\backslash \{ 1\} $ such that $L(n) = \text{least prime factor } p \text{ of } n \text{ such that }$.

Is it true that $\forall n \in Dom(L), \gcd(L(n),n) > 1$ and that $$L(n) =\sum\limits_{k|L(n)} {\varphi (k)} $$?

It seems difficult to me because I tried the following:

Since $\gcd(L(n),n) = L(n)$ (which I don't know how to prove), and some other things I don't quite remember well...

Any hints will help!

Comment: It's trivially true because $L(n)=p\,$ is  prime so the sum is over $k=1$ and $k=p$ which yields $\phi(1) + \phi(p) =  1 + (p-1) = p = L(n)\ \ $

Comment: Generally $\,\sum_{k\mid n}\varphi(k) = n,\,$ e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1854381/242) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Divisor_sum).

Comment: By definition $L(n) \mid n$

Comment: It seems weird to me to include "prime" and "$\leq n$" in the definition of $L(n)$. I would just write "$L(n)=\text{least factor of $n$ greater than $1$}$"; prime-ness and $(\leq n)$-ness are obvious *consequences* of this definition. *(shrug)*